# Как проверить тип данных из DataInputStream перед считыванием?

Tags: java, io

Из массива, содержащего данные типов `int`, `double`, `String`, после проверки типа, записываю их в файл с помощью `DataOutputStream`  методами `writeInt()`, `writeDouble()`, `writeUTF()/writeChars()` соответственно.
Как затем проверить типы данных при считывании их с помощью `DataInputStream`, чтобы выбрать правильный метод `readInt()`, `readDouble()`, `readUTF()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак.

Если сунуться в исходники, то например `writeInt()`, реализован так:

```
 public final void writeInt(int v) throws IOException {
        out.write((v >>> 24) & 0xFF);
        out.write((v >>> 16) & 0xFF);
        out.write((v >>>  8) & 0xFF);
        out.write((v >>>  0) & 0xFF);
        incCount(4); //инкремент указателя потока записи
    }
```

То есть по сути идет запись битов/байтов без указания его типа. И так со всеми остальными типами - записываются голые байты.

Чтобы различать что у вас там записано, вам нужно перед каждой записью вставлять, например байт/тег, который показывает тип следующей записи, типа:

```
static final byte TYPE_INT=1;
static final byte TYPE_DOUBLE=2;

os.writeByte(TYPE_DOUBLE);
os.writeDouble(d);
os.writeByte(TYPE_INT);
os.writeInt(i);
```

Соответственно, при чтении читать байт указывающий тип и ветвиться по его типу что дальше читать.

Вообще по хорошему это все костыли и вам надо смотреть в сторону `ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream` и читать писать сразу объекты через интерфейс `Serializable`, а то и вовсе перейти на Json - но это уже совсем другая история.